# Troubleshooting a Stealth Port that should be Open

Tags: networking, router, routing, port-forwarding

Currently I have a port (7777) that's forwarded to a PC which allows all inbound connections on that port and also has a static IP. This seems like a pretty straightforward setup - however when I try the port's connectivity on [CanYouSeeMe](http://canyouseeme.org/), it times out. Furthermore, I attempted the same test on [PortCheckTool](http://www.portchecktool.com/), and it claims that my port is Stealth.

I've attempted widening the port range on both the port-forward and firewall (to 7775-7779), and also trying to DMZ the IP with no luck.

If anyone has any recommendations on what could be causing my port to remain Stealthed, I'd really appreciate it.

SideNote: The current setup for the router is Shaw Modem/Router to an R7000

Comment: Note that for a port to be open, there must be a process listening on it. Does the LAN IP and port indicated in your NAT rule have a service running? you can check with `netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING` in powershell (as admin) or `netstat -ntlup` in linux.

Comment: Yes, there is a process running although I'll try that command as well. It is listening specifically to 7777 however - not at the range. To be honest, I think the problem might be coming from the Shaw Modem/Router coming before my NetGear router... Currently troubleshooting that as well

Comment: Double NAT issue? Can you put your Modem in bridge mode?

Answer (score 0):

Having the Modem/Router connected to the Router ended up being the problem. Disconnected the second router and Open the port on the Modem/router to make the device work.

Will take @DavidPostill's advice to try bridge mode on the first Modem/Router. And will try normally connecting the two as the Port Range is now open on the first unit as well.